# Search for nodes and keep their path(parent->child) in tree intact

Tags: java

I am trying to search the child nodes based on the search query. I also need to keep their parents(path) in the tree. I am facing difficulty in iterating and filtering the full tree that has been populated with parents and children. The search query will match the nodeName property of the following class. Someone from the community was able to help me write a code that searches for a node and keep their children path intact but does not keep the parent's path.

**My TreeNode class**

```
public class TreeNodeDTO {

/** The id. */
private String id;

/** The nodeName. */
private String nodeName;

/** The children. */
private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

//setters and getters
}
```

**and the search method that searches for a node and keeps its children in the path.**

```
public List< TreeNodeDTO > searchObject( String search ) {
    if ( getNodeName() != null && getNodeName().toLowerCase().contains( search.toLowerCase() ) ) {
        return Arrays.asList( this );
    }
    ArrayList< TreeNodeDTO > resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    if ( getChildren() != null ) {
        for ( TreeNodeDTO child : getChildren() ) {
            resultList.addAll( child.searchObject( search ) );
        }
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Above method returns the tree below for following search

**Search query : "TestProject"**

```
TestProject
        |
        TestChild
```

I am trying hard to get the results in the following form :

```
Project
  |
  SubProject
      |
      DataProject
           |
            TestProject
                |
                 TestChild
```

Comment: Can you also add the structure of the full tree which are providing as the input?

Comment: @vastal you mean the full tree that has been populated? if yes, then there is another subProject with the name "testDemoProject" under Project Node and it has further nodes. But i need the filtered results like above.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TreeNodeDTO {

    /** The id. */
    private String id;
    private TreeNodeDTO parent;

    /** The nodeName. */
    private String nodeName;

    /** The children. */
    private List<TreeNodeDTO> children;

    //setters and getters
    public List< TreeNodeDTO > searchObject( final String search ) {
        final ArrayList< TreeNodeDTO > resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Stack<TreeNodeDTO> candidates = new Stack<>();
        candidates.push( this );
        while ( !candidates.isEmpty() )
        {
            final TreeNodeDTO candidate = candidates.pop();
            if ( StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase( search, candidate.getNodeName() ) )
            {
                resultList.add( candidate );
            }
            candidate.getChildren().forEach( child -> candidates.push( child ) );
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId( final String id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the parent
     */
    public TreeNodeDTO getParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param parent the parent to set
     */
    public void setParent( final TreeNodeDTO parent )
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nodeName
     */
    public String getNodeName()
    {
        return nodeName;
    }

    /**
     * @param nodeName the nodeName to set
     */
    public void setNodeName( final String nodeName )
    {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the children
     */
    public List<TreeNodeDTO> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }

    /**
     * @param children the children to set
     */
    public void setChildren( final List<TreeNodeDTO> children )
    {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

then

```
TreeNodeDTO current = resultList.get(i);
while ( current != null ) {
    current = current.getParent();
    // Do what you want with the tree heirarchy
}
```

Comment: producing the same results as my code above i,e without parents

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the right path and keep track of it. Traverse the tree keeping a queue of `TreeNodeDTO` you are looking at the moment. If a branch does not contain the node you are looking for then remove the branch'root from your list, put the next one and search. Let's say you have this tree:

```
Project
| SubProject1
| SubProject2
  |  TestChild1
  |  TestChild2
```

You are looking for `TestChild1` and you have `Project` as root. You put `Project` as first element in your queue and browse it's `TreeNodeDTO` elements. Put `SubProject1` in the queue and browse its child nodes. `SubProject1` doesn't have what you are looking for and it has no children. Remove `SubProject1` from queue and move to `SubProject2`. Browse `SubProject2` children. Find that `TestChild1` is the one you want, put it in the queue then return the list. If the tree doesn't contain the node you are looking for, you'll get back an empty queue.

I see a Composite pattern in your `TreeNodeDTO` class, use Visitor pattern to implement operation who will be in charge of build your list.

**UPDATE**

Quick solution: use a recursion, here is the code:

```
public class FindNodeRecursively {

  private boolean found = false;

  public void find(String name, TreeNodeDTO tree, Queue<TreeNodeDTO> queue) {
    queue.add(tree);
    if (tree.getId().equals(name)) {
        found = true;
    } else {
        for (TreeNodeDTO child : tree.getChildren()) {
            find(name, child, queue);
            if (found)
                break;
        }
        if (!found)
            queue.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Again, have a look at [composite](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite), [visitor](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor) pattern and how to combine them together.

Comment: Producing so much inconsistent results